# How disable Form::select by condition in template?

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

How disable `Form::selec`t by condition in template?

```
<?=Form::select('bank', $banks, $bank_id, array('class' => "form-control", "disabled" => $disabled)); ?>
```

Where `$disabled` is boolean variable, in any case it disables list.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If i got your point,whenever you have *`disabled`* attribute with any value (even without value) on your input, *It'll get disabled*.
So, In this case you can put your `disabled` index on your array by condition in two ways,

***Shortland IF***

```php
    <?=Form::select('bank', $banks, $bank_id, ($disabled)?['class' => "form-control", "disabled" => "disabled"]:['class'=>"form-control"]); ?>
```

OR

```php
<?php
    if($disabled) 
        Form::select('bank', $banks, $bank_id, array('class' => "form-control", "disabled" => "disabled"));
    else 
        Form::select('bank', $banks, $bank_id, array('class' => "form-control")); 
?>
```